# MSMQ WCF examples (non System.Messaging)

Tags: wcf, msmq

Yes, I have googled and there are loads of samples out there but each and every one is configured differently or is not quite what I am looking for.

I am trying to find a sample where I have MSMQ set up. I want a WCF Service which gets notified as and when a message arrives in the MSMQ queue.

I also want then a client application which binds to that contract and sends a message, placing it in the MSMQ queue.

Can anyone provide examples or links? I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm just getting confused between different types of messaging, different bindings.... list goes on. I am NOT looking for a System.Messaging implementation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find plethora of examples on [MSDN Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) Samples for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21459). When you expand the package look under \WCFWFCardSpace\WCF\Basic\Binding\MsmqIntegration for some basic samples

EDIT:
For transactions it's as simple as:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
public void SubmitPurchaseOrder(MsmqMessage<PurchaseOrder> msg)
{}
```

You can read more about [Poison Message Handling on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789028.aspx) More about the MSMQ on [MSDN - How to: Exchange Messages with WCF Endpoints and Message Queuing Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx)

"When the service reads messages from the target queue under a transaction, the service may fail to process the message for various reasons. The message is then put back into the queue to be read again. To deal with messages that fail repeatedly, a set of poison-message handling properties can be configured in the binding. There are four properties: ReceiveRetryCount, MaxRetryCycles, RetryCycleDelay, and ReceiveErrorHandling. "

EDIT: You would use System.Messaging on the service side.

Comment: from the example, how does one place the message back onto the queue on the service side? Would it be a case of opening the same local queue again and doing a Send()? What about poison messages?

Comment: im sure there was an example/sample somewhere that showed the server side using transactions so if there was an error in processing, it would place it back in the queue, to be processed again/